# Worldwind missing dependencies

Tags: jogl, unsatisfiedlinkerror, worldwind

Worldwind is giving an error about missing dependencies. The executable works on 8/10 computers (intel) all with the same software & versions (Windows 7 w/ Jre8), same graphics cards/drivers (recently new).

On the computers where Worldwind doesn't work, the error was UnsatisfiedLinkError -"gluegen-rt.dll: Can't load AMD 64-bit .dd on a IA 32-bit platform"

To fix this, I downloaded the JOGL dll files for Intel i856, removed the AMD files and the program gives me this error [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mRYRU.png

Any suggestions/comments are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi. Rather add jogamp-fat.jar to the classpath but it will only work with a version of Worldwind relying on JOGL 2.3.2 and later. jogamp-fat.jar contains the native libraries too and GlueGen is able to detect the architecture to extract and load the native libraries supported by your computer (except when restrictive policies or paranoid virus scanners get in its way).

Comment: Do you get the same exception trace before tinkering the DLLs? https://jogamp.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=1219#c7 You might have to disable the automated library loading and to set the Java library path.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out using the jogamp-fat.jar the computer was looking at the 32-bit version of java. Once I installed Java 64-bit version and changed the JAVA_HOME it worked. Thanks!